# Can Not Format Specific Words in Tkinter Label 'text'

Tags: python, tkinter

I were trying to format text prompt (change to bold highlight for words be wrapped by **word**) then pass to `Tkinter` but it not work, it just work when i print to the terminal in notebook. Is it possible to do this in Tkinter?

```
def format_text(text):
    # Split the text into lines
    lines = text.split('\n')

    formatted_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        my_font = Font(family="Courier", size=11)
        # Check for bold text
        if line.startswith('**') and line.endswith('**'):
            my_font.configure(weight="bold")
            line = line[2:-2]  # Remove the '**' from the start and end

        # Add the formatted line to the list
        formatted_lines.append(line)

    # Join all the formatted lines into a single string
    formatted_text = '\n'.join(formatted_lines)

    # Create a label with the formatted text
    botchat = Label(chatframe, text=f'{formatted_text}', font=my_font, bg='pink', fg='#630b12', justify='center', anchor='center', wraplength=590, cursor='star')
    botchat.pack(anchor='w', ipadx=4, ipady=3, pady=2, padx=6)
```

Comment: You are generating a new value of `my_font` for each line of text - but it overwrites the previous value, so only the value for the final line actually gets used by the Label.  A Label doesn't support varying fonts anyway, you'd need to use a Text widget instead.

Comment: you may have to use widget `Text` and assign `tag` to `words` and later use tag to change font. [Python: How to change color in Text using tags — furas.pl](https://blog.furas.pl/python-tkinter-how-to-change-color-in-text-using-tags-gb.html)